I am worried about my mother's wellbeing
I am worried about my mom, She really is a goddess but there are some downfalls. She is overprotective, lives in an arrested development, receptive to social media fake alert messages and constantly lives in fear by the words others put in her mind. Most of all, she is selfless, what exactly I mean is she works in such a way even though it isn't necessary at all. she works to exhaustion. To the point where she actually brings it on her health, when we at home know she doesn't even have to do that in the first place despite workers and my help. she doesn't even consider taking care of herself. It is really breaking, irritating at times, annoying to look her like that. She is fine but her recurring health problems which she brought herself are something I am deeply angry about. I have been trying my very best and it's been years and years and years , nothing changed. I actually kind of hate her for doing all the unnecessary chores which cost her health frequently. I pray, I help my best, I want to see her showing no sign of sickness. But, she doesn't care. For all I know, she is bringing all these ailments on herself and kind of blames me as the reason when I couldn't help.
